# Java non-web deployment to Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-worker-roles

I am writing Java application on Azure cloud services
one of my application components is non-web background processing,supposed to be a "worker role" in azure terminology, I am using azure plugin to eclipse.

It seems like there is no way to deploy java application which is not a web application! cause for every deployment I must specify a web server to the package.

Is there a way to define a worker role (java main application) to be deployed to azure cloud services?